# Xcode func used in another View Controller

Tags: mysql, swift, database, xcode, func

I have this func in a Swift file, and it returns the value of the data in the database and prints it out in the counsel.
I want to use the value in the other View Controller but I can't get this to work, so I hope somebody can help me.
It is the `nameUser`, `statusUser` and `pointUser` I like to use in other View Controller.

```
 import Foundation
  import UIKit
  var code = "100"
  var getStatusUSer = ""

class getJSON: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate
{
//properties
var data : NSMutableData = NSMutableData()

func downloadItems()
{
let url = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string:                           "http://www.hholm.dk/time_app/qrcode4.php")! as URL)
    url.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "username=\(code)"
    url.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    print(url.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8))

    var session: URLSession!
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self,  delegateQueue: nil)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url as URLRequest)

    task.resume()

}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data)
{
    self.data.append(data as Data);
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)
{
    if error != nil
    {
        print("Not Found", error)

    }
    else
    {
        print("Ok")
        self.parseJSON()
    }

}


func parseJSON()
{

    var jsonResult: NSArray = NSArray()

    do
    {
        jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self.data as Data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray

        print("jsonResult.count",jsonResult.count)
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print("jsonResult: ", error)
    }


    var jsonElement: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
    var contador = 0
    for i in (0..<jsonResult.count)
    {
        jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

        if let nameUser = jsonElement["name"] as? String,
            let pointUser = jsonElement["point"] as? String,
            let statusUser = jsonElement["status"] as? String
        {
            getStatusUSer = statusUser
            print("Name: ", nameUser)
            print("Status: ", statusUser)
            print("Point: ", pointUser)

        }

    }
}

}
```

Hi Woof this is what i have in my viewcontroler:

```
import UIKit

class inputcodeViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField!

@IBAction func but(_ sender: Any) {
    downloadItems()
            }


func downloadItems(){
    let getJson = GetJSON()
    //setting the delegate
    getJson.delegate = self
    //starting download
    getJson.downloadItems()
}
}

    extension inputcodeViewController: GetJSONDelegate {
    func didReceiveValues(name: String, status: String, point: String){
        //now you can use values in your view controller
    }

}
```

how can i print the values

Comment: Take the function out of the view controller and put it in a class then use that class. It is not a good practice for view controllers to call functions in other view controllers.

Comment: Hi ryantxr, do you have a eksempel. i have the func in a swiftfile and not a viewcontroler filer. sorry but im new to xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use protocol to return those values:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
var code = "100"
var getStatusUSer = ""

//define the protocol
protocol GetJSONDelegate {
      func didReceiveValues(name: String, status: String, point: String)
}
//I've changed the first char of the class name to uppercase 
class GetJSON: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate{
//properties
var data : NSMutableData = NSMutableData()

//delegate
var delegate: GetJSONDelegate?

func downloadItems(){
let url = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string:                           "http://www.hholm.dk/time_app/qrcode4.php")! as URL)
    url.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "username=\(code)"
    url.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    print(url.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8))

    var session: URLSession!
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self,  delegateQueue: nil)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url as URLRequest)

    task.resume()

}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data)
{
    self.data.append(data as Data);
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)
{
    if error != nil
    {
        print("Not Found", error)

    }
    else
    {
        print("Ok")
        self.parseJSON()
    }

}


func parseJSON()
{

    var jsonResult: NSArray = NSArray()

    do
    {
        jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self.data as Data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray

        print("jsonResult.count",jsonResult.count)
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print("jsonResult: ", error)
    }


    var jsonElement: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
    var contador = 0
    for i in (0..<jsonResult.count)
    {
        jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

        if let nameUser = jsonElement["name"] as? String,
            let pointUser = jsonElement["point"] as? String,
            let statusUser = jsonElement["status"] as? String
        {
            getStatusUSer = statusUser
            print("Name: ", nameUser)
            print("Status: ", statusUser)
            print("Point: ", pointUser)

           //here we will return received data to the delegate
          self.delegate?.didReceiveValues(name: nameUser, status: statusUser, point: pointUser)
        }

    }
}

}
```

Now we need to set your controller as a delegate for that protocol:

```
//this is an example, you need to add the methods described in your controller where you want to use those values

class YourViewController: UIViewController{
     // the method that is called by you to get values
     func downloadItems(){
          let getJson = GetJSON()
          //setting the delegate
          getJson.delegate = self
          //starting download
          getJson.downloadItems()
     }
}

//defining protocol methods in the extension of the view controller
extension YourViewController: GetJSONDelegate {
     func didReceiveValues(name: String, status: String, point: String){
          //now you can use values in your view controller
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Woof, this seems to work, but how can i print the point in the viewcontroler, if i only want to print the point

Comment: Don't understand what are you going to do. You said that you want to use those parameters in your controller, so here you go, use them as you wish. If you want to send only one, then change the protocol func as you need. It will also require to change it same way in the extension YourViewController: GetJSONDelegate and in the self.delegate?.didReceiveValues

Comment: hi Woof, if you can show me an example how i can print this parameters in the viewcontroler, like when i i push a button

Comment: If you will push a button that will call the method downloadItems() it will call the protocol method, that's it. In your controller extension that method will return all values that you need. The code above is complete, values are set. Just call the downloadItems from your controller after clicking it's button

Comment: i have add some code, that i have in the viewcontroler, look above

Comment: Yes, I see. It should work. In you extension inside this func where I put the comment "//now you can use values in your view controller" you can make print(point) to check that all is working correctly. Is that what you need? What are you going to do with those values?

Comment: Yes it work fine. what i would like to, when i input a code in a text feld, it chk, if the status is "1", and if it is, the chance to a new viewcontroler.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand what are you trying to do. Your first question was about an ability to receive values in the controller. Now you have it. If you need something to do with them, please specify your question with the code, open a new ticket or edit the current one